# assigning name to each segment of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have an image of size 640X480. I want to segment it into 40X40 and then apply a common operation on each segment. so I did something like this:

```
A= imread('image.jpg');
for a=0:11;
    for b= 0:15;
        B=A((1+a*40):(a+1)*40,(1+b*40):(b+1)*40);
             ....... the common program for each segment........
        C= result;        %result of the operation
    end
end
```

My question is how can I label **C** differently for each segment so that I can use these  further for adding these segments back or else.
I tried defining B something like this:

```
A= imread('image.jpg');
for a=0:11;
    for b= 0:15;
        B=A((1+a*40):(a+1)*40,(1+b*40):(b+1)*40);
             ....... the common program for each segment........
        C((a+1),(b+1))= result    %result of the operation
    end
end
```

Had it worked, I could have used **C(i,j)** as variable(name) but it ended as an error. What else I can do for *labeling the results of the **for** loop.*

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: What error do you get? `C((a+1),(b+1))` is fine for *scalar* results, is your result a matrix?

Comment: yes, the result is also an 40X40 image matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Use [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) for `C`

```
C{ a+1, b+1 } = result;
```

You many also want to check [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your result is always 40x40, I would use a 4d result matrix:

```
%preallocate at the beginning
C=nan(11,15,40,40)
```

And to fill within the loop

```
C(a+1,b+1,:,:)=result
```

Comment: I tried what you said with this simple 9X9 matrix. But I got many matrices with different matrices in return and the name also goes like **C(:,:,x,y){x,y=1,2,3] **. what kind of name it is? and also its not unique, there are more than one matrix for same **C(:,:,x,y){x,y=1,2,3] **.                       A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;8,7,6,5,4,3,3,2,9;2,1,4,5,6,7,5,8,4;0,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,3;1,3,4,6,8,0,8,3,6;1,4,2,6,4,8,8,3,6;1,2,4,2,5,6,4,8,3;6,4,3,2,6,8,5,3,4;3,4,2,4,3,5,4,6,7];
C=nan(2,2,3,3)
for a=0:2;
    for b=0:2;
         B= A((1+a*3):(a+1)*3,(1+b*3):(b+1)*3);
          C(a+1,b+1,:,:)=B
    end
end